# xgboost classifier predicted negative probabilities

Tags: python, classification, xgboost

I'm using XGBoost for a binary classification problem. There is no negative label, only 1 and 0.

I tunned the hyperparameters using Bayesian optimization then tried to train the final model with the optimized hyperparameters.

`Mdl_XGB = xgb.train(OptimizedParams, dtrain)`

`scores_train = Mdl_XGB.predict(dtrain)`

`scores_test = Mdl_XGB.predict(dtest)`

My problem is that the predicted scores for both train and test sets include both negative values and numbers greater than one. The scores are between -0.23 and 1.13.

Shouldn't these scores present the probability of belonging to class 1 (positive class)?

Comment: Can you include the code for model creation and the outputs? As a side note: the word "scores" might be confusing here since it is usually used for performance scores like accuracy. It is more common to write `pred_train = Mdl_XGB.predict(dtrain)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the option objective = binary:logistic to get probabilities between 0 and 1, otherwise you only get relative scores.

Comment: Honestly: no. You shouldn't train a model without looking at the learning options.

Comment: I guess I gave you the answer anyway.

Comment: Added to the dictionary of optimized parameters. It worked. Thanks!

Comment: I think it's worse than just "otherwise you only get relative scores". With the defaults, you are performing regression, with mse loss!

Comment: You are right. But couldn’t you use the output of such regression as a « score » ?

Comment: I too am getting negative predictions passed to a custom metric function even with objective='binary:logistic'. I get values between -0.1978 and 0.1999...